# Mapping rows in one table to columns in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Domain` table with multiple rows:

**Domain Table**

[image]

Now I want to write a stored procedure where for each matching Param_Value
in my `Domain` table, a new record is created in a new `Matching` table for each Domain with a new column, like:

**Matching Table**

[image]

My stored procedure currently looks like this:

```
create Procedure UpdateMatchingTable
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @Param_Value varChar(20), @Param_Abbrev varChar(20),
        @Param_Domain varChar(20)
    SET @Param_Abbrev = (SELECT @Param_Domain from ref_codes
        where @Param_Value = (SELECT @Param_Value from originTable))
    IF @Param_Domain is not null
    INSERT INTO  MatchingTable
    values(@Param_Domain,@Param_Abbrev)

END 
GO
```

My problem is, the stored procedure does not compile.

Comment: You can't do something like this: `SELECT @Param_Value from originTable`.
It violates the rules of physics.

Comment: @NiranjanRajawat That's valid SQL, but it won't do what he expects. It'll return the value of the variable for every row, not the values of the columns named in the variable. Not the law of physics, but it certainly goes against intuiton :D

Comment: @Alejandro You are right, silly me, didn't think of that, and yes certainly it won't be usefully in what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: The specific task you've given us almost certainly requires dynamic sql (ie sp_executesql) to achieve. However, you might find you get a better response if you tell us what you're trying to achieve. There might be a better way?

Comment: @all thanks for making this Point clear. In my Database there are f.e. approximately 140 different countries. In my `Domain Table` there is for every Country a matching Abbreviation. I want a non static SQL Procedure, match this tuples in an extra table.

Comment: What logic determines that these are the correct pairings of `HERK_LAND` and `AGE_GROUP` values in your example? Why does Central Afrika have an `AGE_GROUP` of 2 and Europe a value of 1, rather than the other way round?